# Exponentially Weighing Moving Average (EWMA) for weekly data

Tags: weighted-mean, exponential-smoothing, moving-average, volatility-forecasting

I'm aware that the typical EWMA approach is applied over larger time periods (say for Volatility, where lambda = 94% and all weights add up to 100% for stock returns data from last 5 years).  Reference: [Investopedia: EWMA](http://www.investopedia.com/articles/07/ewma.asp)

Is there a way to apply EWMA approach for weekly data?  For example, I have Mon-Fri observations as 60, 35, 50, 80, 90 and I need to assign more weights to the recent observation (instead of using a simple average).  Please suggest an alternative if that suits my situation better.

Comment: Thanks. Again, I'm not working on price data series.  For e.g., I'm working on aircraft noise and it is quite volatile.  My goal is to come up with a weighting scheme that assigns more W to the recent observation (in say weekly data, 5 observations). I was wondering if EWMA is even relevant here.